# How to know if app is in RUNNING state to kill spark-submit process?

Tags: apache-spark

I am creating a shell script which will be executed from Jenkins because we have many streaming jobs and it seems easier to manager from Jenkins. So I have created the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
spark-submit "spark parameters here" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
processId=$!
echo $processId
sleep 5m
kill $processId
```

If I don't have a sleep, the spark-submit process is killed immediately and no spark application is submitted. And if there is a sleep the spark-submit process gets enough time to submit the spark application.

My question is, is there a better way to know if the spark application is in RUNNING state so that the spark-submit process can be killed ?

Spark 1.6.0 with YARN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `spark-submit` your Spark application and use `yarn application -status <ApplicationId>` as described in [application](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#application) section:

> Prints the status of the application.

You could get `<ApplicationId>` from the logs of `spark-submit` (in `client` deploy mode) or use `yarn application -list -appType SPARK -appStates RUNNING`.

Comment: I am using yarn, so I used the yarn application -list & grep application name to get the application id, all in the while with sleep to check the update status.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Spark version you are using or if you are running in standalone mode, but anyway, you can use [the REST API](http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api) for submitting/killing your apps. The last time I checked it was pretty much undocumented, but it worked properly.

When you submit an application, you will get a `submissionId` which you can use later for either getting the current state or killing it. The possible states are documented [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/master/DriverState.scala):

```
  // SUBMITTED: Submitted but not yet scheduled on a worker
  // RUNNING: Has been allocated to a worker to run
  // FINISHED: Previously ran and exited cleanly
  // RELAUNCHING: Exited non-zero or due to worker failure, but has not yet started running again
  // UNKNOWN: The state of the driver is temporarily not known due to master failure recovery
  // KILLED: A user manually killed this driver
  // FAILED: The driver exited non-zero and was not supervised
  // ERROR: Unable to run or restart due to an unrecoverable error (e.g. missing jar file)
```

This is specially useful for long-running apps (e.g. streaming), since you don't have to babysit the shell script.

Comment: I am using Spark 1.6.0 with YARN, I think the REST interface is available only for standalone mode. I don't see anything running on port 6066 as mentioned on the link provided.